# zsh completion for scp completes local users when connecting to remote server

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete, scp

Lets say, I have one file in current directory, `test.txt` and I want to transfer it using `scp` to remote server.

When I use completion, ie:

```
scp -rp test<TAB>
```

instead of completing the rest of the filename for me, zsh completion offers:

```
scp -rp test<TAB>
test.txt
testuser
```

`testuser` happens to be local user on my system. Why would zsh completion complete local user, when I am connecting to remote server ?

That seems like a useless and stupid rule.

`scp` is using same completion file as ssh `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_ssh`, and `ssh` command has the same behavior, although in case of `ssh` it is less annoying, since ssh is not supposed to complete local filenames.

**How can I modify the completion rules for `scp` so that it only offers local filenames, not local users?**

## UPDATE FOR BOUNTY

The accepted solution works for `scp`, but the problem still persist for `ssh`. When I want to connect to `myserver.domain.org` and use completion:

```
ssh m<TAB>
```

the completion system offers `myserver.domain.org` (which is desired), but also local users `man` and `messagebus`, which is idiotic.

How can I change the completion system for `ssh/scp` so that instead of completing all local users from `/etc/passwd`, I can specify (hardcoded) list of users that I want to complete?

So, in other words:
I don't want to disable user completion for `ssh`, as the accepted answer does for `scp`. But I want to provide my own list of users that will be completed, instead using all local users from `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*:scp:*' tag-order '! users'
```

This tells the completion system that, for `scp`, do not try to complete `users` unless no other completions can be found. (See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-tag_002dorder_002c-completion-style)

---

To specify a list of the only user names that should be completed when using `ssh`:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' users alice bob carol
```

(See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-users_002c-completion-style)

Comment: thank you. That works.

Comment: @400theCat I updated my answer for the bounty.

Comment: thank you. The `zstyle` rule for `ssh` works beautifully.

Comment: @400theCat So, do I get the bounty? 